# PrimeNG Chips: Add tag when semicolon is typed

Tags: angular, primeng

The [PrimeNG Chips](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/chips) component adds a tag when the `Enter` key is pressed. I also want to accept the tag after typing a semicolon. Is it possible to trigger the `Enter` key when the semicolon key is pressed?

```
semicolumn(e) {
    if (e.key == ';') {

    }
}

<p-chips [addOnTab]="true" [addOnBlur]="true" (keydown)="semicolumn($event)"></p-chips>
```

For example, when the user types in `test;`, it would be like he typed `test` followed by `Enter`.

Comment: Your question is very hard to understand as formatted. You should provide more context, ideally all the relevant code from the component .ts file (including the component declaration itself, so we can see what "p-chips" refers to), as well as all the relevant code from the HTML file.

Comment: i dont know what is hard to understand i want when user type ; that trigger enter ...so if i type test; it will be like i test and then clicked enter

Comment: It's also unclear what you mean by "trigger enter". What happens currently when you press the enter key, and how is this event triggered? Do you have a `<form>` tag with an `onsubmit` callback?

Comment: right now when i click enter it create input tag of what i write...but i want to achive that with semicolon.

Comment: And where is the `<input>` tag? Is it in the HTML for the `p-chips` component? Or is it a sibling of the `<p-chips>` HTML tag? Where is your `semicolumn(e)` function defined? This kind of relevant info is required to understand your question, and it's why you should provide more code in your question.

Comment: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/chips there is what i want to achive but with semicolon, this only work with enter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193426/discussion-between-none-and-dukeluke).

Comment: are you trying to detect the key press event for semicolon ?

Comment: no, im trying when user click on semicolon to behave like he clicked enter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Triggering the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key events appears to be tricky. However, since you set the `addOnBlur` option on the PrimeNG Chips component:

```
<p-chips [addOnTab]="true" [addOnBlur]="true" (keydown)="onKeyDown($event)" ></p-chips>
```

you can accept the tag by calling `blur()` and `focus()` successively on the input element when the semicolon is typed:

```
onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
  if (event.key === ";") {
    event.preventDefault();
    const element = event.target as HTMLElement;
    element.blur();
    element.focus();
  }
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xhq7fw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for a demo.

Comment: How to achieve by pasting comma separator value like aaa,bbb,ccc at once on above example

Comment: @senthilkumar: same as ';'.  if (event.key === ";" || event.key === ",")

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@ViewChild` and control the `primeng` component:

**my-comp.component.ts**

```js
import { Chips } from 'primeng/chips';
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
    
export class MyComp implement OnInit {
    @ViewChild(Chips) chips: Chips;

    constructor(){}

    ngOnInit(){}
    
    onKeyDown(event) {
        if (event.key === ";") {
        // use the internal method to set the new value
            this.chips.writeValue([...this.chips.value, event.target.value]) // don't push the new value inside the array, create a new reference
            this.chips.cd.detectChanges(); // use internal change detection
            event.preventDefault();    //prevent ';' to be written
            event.target.value = "";   // reset the input value
        }
    }
}
```

**my-comp.component.html**

```html
<p-chips (keydown)="onKeyDown($event)"></p-chips>
```

and then you can get all the values using `[(ngmodel)]` or `formcontrolname` (in a form).

Answer (score 0):

```
  <p-chips separator=";"></p-chips>
```

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate in addition to help solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is simple enough

`<p-chips [addOnTab]="true" [addOnBlur]="true" formControlName="tags" (keydown)="semicolumn($event)"></p-chips>`

using the `semicolumn` function:

```
semicolumn(event) {
  if (event.key === ';') {
    const arr = [...this.form.get('tags').value, event.target.value];
    this.form.get('tags').setValue([...arr]);
    event.target.value = '';
  }
}
```

I think this is the perfect way to set add the new value and reset the input to receive a new value